# parse date showing wrong date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse below string into date but its showing wrong date

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dateformat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sDate1 = "2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00";
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(sDate1);
        System.out.println(sDate1 + "\t" + date1);
    }
}
```

Doubt: why even its working if pattern is not matching with input string ?

Secondly, why its showing wrong date ?

```
Output : 2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00  Fri Jan 05 00:10:00 IST 2018
```

Suggestions please

Comment: As far as the first question: by default the parser is `lenient`: If no exact match is found, it tries to parse anyway and in your case succeeds.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd") yyy-mm-dd here is for input date format, not for output.

Comment: @AxborAxrorov She is complaining about wrong Date not wrong format

Comment: import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class SimpleDateFormatExample3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 try {
  Date date = formatter.parse("31/03/2015");
  System.out.println("Date is: "+date);
 } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
output is: Date is: Tue Mar 31 00:00:00 IST 2015

Comment: @ScaryWombat and what am I about? She must choose right format to parse the date.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha i have mentioned the output and that is the actual format

Comment: The format you should use is: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`
So: 
MM -> month, 
mm -> minute

Comment: @Adly i have already mentioned the correct format and gave a sample program i.e; mm is for minute and MM is for month

Comment: Use modern *java.time* classes: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00" ).toLocalDate().toString()`

Comment: @RobertKock `SimpleDateFormat` is more complicated than that. While it’s true what you say, leniency is not relevant here. Setting the format non-lenient still gave `Fri Jan 05 00:10:00 CET 2018` on my computer.

Comment: Elena, I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5):

m   is for Minute in hour

try

```
String sDate1 = "2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00";
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1);
System.out.println(sDate1 + "\t" + date1);
```

**output**

> 2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00 Fri Oct 05 00:00:00 JST 2018

Comment: m is for Minute in hour...meaning ?

Comment: lowercase `m` will parse the `Minute` but you want uppercase `M` to parse the `Month`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using Date? It is deprecated and not useful since java 8. It is better to use LocalDateTime, LocalDate or LocalTime now.(Update base on comment of user https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v)

```
        String date = "2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00";
        OffsetDateTime result = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(result);
        System.out.println(localDate);
```

Comment: Since the string has a UTC offset and no time zone, the best class to use here is `OffsetDateTime`. When you do, you also don’t need to specify a formatter since the string is in the default (ISO 8601) format for `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: The comment by Ole V.V. is correct: The `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate here than `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

The format you should use is: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

- MM > month
- mm > minute

Answer (score 0):

Cutting off the rest of the string which is not needed is one way to do it. Keep the substring of the part you need and the Date should be working fine.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dateformat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sDate1 = "2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00";
        String formatedDate = sDate1.substring(0,10);
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(formatedDate);
        System.out.println(sDate1 + "\t" + date1);
    }
}
```

> FormatedDate is: 2018-10-05
>
> The output is: 2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00  -   Fri Oct 05 00:00:00 UTC
>   2018

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong format to parse the date!
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")` yyyy-mm-dd here is format for input (which you are trying to parse).
you must use format `yyyy-MM-dd` .

for formatting output you must write code like:

```
class DateUtils {
    private static SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale("ru","RU"));
    private static SimpleDateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale("ru","RU"));

    public static String formatDate(String date) {
        return toFormat.format(fromFormat.parse(date));
    }
}
```

example of using:

```
DateUtils.formatDate("2018-10-05T00:00:00-05:00");
```

and the result is:

```
05 OCT 2018
```